# Laravel Post Form data

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble taking data from a form in my laravel app, and displaying it using another method in the same controller.

This is my FormController

```
class ForumController extends Controller {
+
+   private $name,
+           $description;
+
+   public function __construct() {
+       $this->middleware('auth');
+   }
+
+   /**
+    * Show the form for creating a new resource.
+    *
+    * @return Response
+    */
+   public function create()
+   {
+       return view('forum.create');        
+
+       $this->name = Input::post('name');  
+   }
+
+   /**
+    * Show the details of their input once its created
+    */
+   public function created()
+   {   
+       var_dump($this->name);
+   }
+}
```

This is my Routes.php

```
Route::get('/group/create', 'ForumController@create');
+Route::post('/group/create', 'ForumController@created');
```

This is my forum create view.

```
@extends('app')
+
+@section('content')
+   
+   <div class="container">
+       <h1>Create a Forum</h1>
+       <hr>
+       
+       <div class="panel panel-default">
+           <div class="panel-heading">Create your own forum here!</div>
+           
+           <div class="panel-body">
+               @if (count($errors) > 0)
+                   <div class="alert alert-danger">
+                       <strong>Whoops!</strong>There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
+       <ul>
+           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
+               <li>{{ $error }}</li>
+           @endforeach
+       </ul>
+               @endif
+               <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('/group/create') }}">
+
+                   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
+                   
+                   <div class="form-group">
+                       <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
+                       <div class="col-md-6">
+                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" min="1" max="20">
+                       </div>
+                   </div>
+
+                   <div class="form-group">
+                       <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>
+                       <div class="col-md-6">
+                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" min="1" max="255">
+                       </div>
+                   </div>
+                   
+                   <div class="form-group">
+                       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
+                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
+                               Create
+                           </button>
+                       </div>
+                   </div>
+               </form>
+           </div>
+       </div>  
+   </div>  
+@stop
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the point of failure on your example is that PHP is not going to persist `$this->name` when you load the `created` route.  In fact, as the commenter stated, `$this->name` is never set because you have a return statement prior to its definition.

After you set `$this->name` in the create method. When you navigate to the created route, `$this->name` is no longer set, even if you were to move your return statement after the setting of name.

You will need to pesist the data in a database/session/cache or redirect from create method to created method passing the data.

```
public function create() 
{
    // Handle POST Here
    if (Input::has('name')) {
       $this->name = Input::get('name'); 

        // $this->name is redundant but even still...
        return Redirect::to('created', array('name' => $this->name));
    }

    return view('forum.create');        
}
```

Comment: $this->name is never set. As it is dead code as he has already returned in his controller method.

Answer (score 2):

```
$name = Input::get('name');
```

or check:

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

You should have this code in the controller method you're posting to.
And you can save the values in session or flashdata if you want something to save one request and then throw it away. And you need to redirect the view to something also a view or a route.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#flash-data